# Make Textview display SQLite information

Tags: java, android, sqlite, textview

Oke so I have the next code in my DataBaseHandler

```
    // Getting single contact
    Database getContact(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_MOVIES, new String[] { KEY_ID,
    ,KEY_SUM,KEY_ACT,KEY_TRAILER,KEY_PREVIEW,KEY_DIR,KEY_WRI }, KEY_ID + "=?",
    new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    Database contact = new Database(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
    cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3),cursor.getString(4),cursor.getString(5),
cursor.getString(6),cursor.getString(7));

return contact;
    }
```

info.java class

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.info);
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
                // for this example i want to read out ID 15 in my database
        db.getContact(15);

    }
```

database.java class

```
// getting movie_director
            public String getMD(){
                return this._movie_director;
            }

            // setting movie_director
            public void setMD(String movie_director){   
                this._movie_director = movie_director;
            }
```

info.xml file containing the textView

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

In this case I want to show the movie director in the textview from the SQLite database, but I'm stuck after the `db.getContact(15);` (see info.java class). I can call the database, but I have no idea on how to retrieve the info from my DatabaseHandler and put it in a Textview. I tried to do `db.getMD();` but it doesn't work to retrieve it this way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `getContact()` function is returning a `Database` Object, but you are calling the method `getMD()` to your `DatabaseHandler`.

I think first of all you should rename the class `Database` to something like **Contact** and return that in your `getContact()` function. After that store the returned value in a variable and call the function `getMD()`. The code can be something like this:

```
  DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
  Contact contact = db.getContact(15); //This is your what you call Database object

  //get View element
  TextView contactTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
  //Set contact information in the TextView
  contactTextView.setText(contact.getMD());
```

Comment: Thank you so so much <3 that did the trick! YOU my friend are AWESOME